How to set up visual studio for monogame android
I am new to monogame development and C# and I try to build my very first project. But I cant build it
In Activity1.cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;

The error msg is:
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
I installed nuget packages like monogame.framework.andoid or openGl but did not work. I use SDK 7.0 (Nougat)
